# how to change credentials of virtual machine

Tags: azure

I want to change credentials of my virtual machine. First want to take backup,and then change username and password of virtualmachine (RDP). I'm not able to get settings in azure portal. Since our website is up and running, we don want to take risk, so need proper guidance.. Kindly guide me steps how to continue in azure portal.

Comment: You should be able to change the admin password.

Comment: thats not exactly true, you can create a new user with specific password or reset existing user password using `password reset` feature from the portal.

Comment: not only password,, i want to change rdp(virtual machine) name .... not azure portal credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the particular VM on azure portal and goto **[`Reset Password`](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-reset-rdp.md#windows-vms-in-the-classic-deployment-model)**

Add the new username there and configure with the password

Comment: thank u,,but is it safe to proceed... i have rdp downloaded.. nw this new rdp, can i download,, n will it contain all data?

Comment: what do you mean by it will contain all data?

Comment: website data.. which is running on server of virtual machine

Comment: you cant do anything with that. its just to connect to the vm